# Rails 4, apply filters to mounted engines actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, when working with an application with a mounted engine, there are two `ApplicationController`:

- `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base` for the application
- `class MyEngine::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base` for the engine

As the Engine `ApplicationController` does not inherit from the application `ApplicationController`, filters applied to the application are not applied to the Engine.

How can I apply a `before_action`, `after_action` or `around_action` to all the application routes, included the ones from mounted engines? Of course, without touching the engine code.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an initializer that changes ActionController::Base

```
 class ActionController::Base
   before_action :do_a_thing
   def do_a_thing
     puts "did something" #or whatever
   end
 end
```

Stick this in an rb file and put it in config/initializers

Answer (score 1):

FWIW in 201, circa rails 5.2, there is a better way of doing this. The gist of this question's issue revolves around the [isolation of the Engine's namespace](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#critical-files).

Add the methods that you want in your main apps ApplicationController, into your Rails Engine's ApplicationHelper module.

Then mix them into your application via [an Engine load hook](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#what-are-on-load-hooks-questionmark). (in your engine.rb file)

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller_base) {
  include Yourengine::ApplicationHelper
}
```

The methods are now available in your application's ApplicationController.

You can now add the ***before_action*** to your Rails application's Application Controller. I am of the opinion that the before action should be an explicit operation in your Rails application not in the Rails engine, i.e. a child shouldn't force their parent to do something.

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter in engine.rb file of your engine

```
initializer :append_before_action do
   ActionController::Base.send :before_action, :do_a_thing
end
```