# How to trigger before_actions in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a set of before_actions defined in my application controller, such as

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_current_user!
....
end
```

I have my routes setup to include Sidekiq

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  require "sidekiq/web"
  require "sidekiq/cron/web"

  authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.authorized?("sidekiq", "index") } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq"
  end
```

When the user opens the sidekiq URL in the app, the before_actions are not triggered. How can I make those before_actions to be triggered?

Comment: Maybe it will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909519/rails-4-apply-filters-to-mounted-engines-actions

Comment: You're approaching the problem wrong. Instead of trying to make Sidekiq execute code in a class thats not it's superclass which is a fools errand you need to extract the code that you want to be able to reuse into a module and have it run when the module is included. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52998753/544825 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-mixins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback. I couldn't get any of those working though. So here is what I finally did:

I took the logic out of the application controller and put it into an own class

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_current_user!

  def set_current_user!
    return unless current_user

    Current.me(current_user)
  end
  ....
end
```

into

```
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :user
  attribute :auth_profiles

  def self.me(user_)
    Current.user = user_
    Current.auth_profiles = AuthProfileUser.where(user_id: user_.id).pluck(:auth_profile_id)
  end
end
```

The authorized? method then executes the isolated code if it hasn't done so before.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ....
  def authorized?(controller_, action_)
    Current.me(self) if Current.auth_profiles.nil? 
    .....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, you cannot do it in the routes way. However there is a way to handle this directly in the `application_controller.rb`

i am sharing a code snippet, you can customize it in any way.

```
## in application_controller.rb
before_filter :http_basic_auth_for_admins

  def check_admin_url
    request.path_info.include?('/sidekiq')
  end

  def http_basic_auth_for_admins
    if Rails.env == 'production' && check_admin_url
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic 'Production' do |name, password|
        name == 'mYtOUgHpasW0RD' && password == 'mYtOUgHpasW0RD'
      end
    end
  end
```